# MySQL Combined sales report

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: "prueba" is the catalogue with all the descriptions and codes for the products.

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
cod varchar(10) NO  PRI     
nom varchar(100)    NO          
tip varchar(50) NO          
des varchar(500)    NO          
pre double  NO          
can int(11) YES     1   
cla varchar(3)  NO          
fcm varchar(20) YES         
cmb char(1) NO      0
```

And "venta" contains the sales:

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
id  int(255)    NO  PRI     auto_increment
can int(11) NO          
tot double  NO          
fec varchar(30) NO          
hor varchar(20) NO          
cod_f   varchar(10) YES MUL     
per_f   varchar(30) YES MUL     
tdt varchar(15) NO          
des double  YES         
com varchar(500)    YES         
cdv varchar(15) NO          
cliente varchar(100)    YES         
fdc varchar(30) YES         
local   varchar(25) NO          
trans   varchar(10) YES
```

I need to do a report that shows how much of certain code was sold on certain shop. So, in "venta" cod_f is the code, can is the quantity sold, tdt indicates the type of the transaction and local is where was the transaction made. So if the transaction was a sale, tdt = 'V'. The following query shows me only the codes of the transactions made on that store.

```
select prueba.cod, ifnull(sum(venta.can),0)
from venta, prueba
where 
venta.cod_f = prueba.cod and 
tdt = 'V' and
local = 'XCSUR' and
yearweek( DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(fec, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') ) between yearweek(curdate() - interval 8 week) and yearweek(curdate())
group by cod_f
order by CHAR_LENGTH(cod_f), cod_f;
```

What I want is to show even the codes that are not part of the sales showing them as 0, F/E:

My query shows:

```
2010    1
2012    5
2013    2
2022    1
```

And omits the inbetween codes. What I want is something like:

```
2010    1
2011    0
2012    5
2013    2
2014    0
2022    1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some general comments:

- You should use explicit `join` syntax.
- You should use table aliases.
- You do not need to format a date after you have converted it.
- You should store dates in native formats, instead of as strings.
- The `group by` and `order by` should refer to fields in the `select`, if appropriate (`p.cod` vs `v.cod_f`).

Then, the approach to your question is to move the `where` conditions into conditional aggregation statements.  So, if each code ever appears in the data (even without the conditions on `tdt` and `local`), then it will be in the output.  Try this:

```
select p.cod, coalesce(sum(case when tdt = 'V' and local = 'XCSUR' then v.can else 0 end), 0)
from venta v join
     prueba p
     on v.cod_f = p.cod
where tdt = 'V' and
      local = 'XCSUR' and
      yearweek(STR_TO_DATE(fec, '%d/%m/%Y')) between yearweek(curdate() - interval 8 week) and
                                                     yearweek(curdate())
group by p.cod
order by CHAR_LENGTH(p.cod), p.cod;
```

EDIT:

You can also do this with an outer join by rearranging the tables.  You have to put the filtering clauses in the `on` clause:

```
select p.cod, coalesce(sum(v.can), 0)
from prueba p left join
     venta v
     on v.cod_f = p.cod and
        yearweek(STR_TO_DATE(fec, '%d/%m/%Y')) between yearweek(curdate() - interval 8 week) and
                                                       yearweek(curdate()) and
        v.tdt = 'V' and
        v.local = 'XCSUR'
group by p.cod
order by CHAR_LENGTH(p.cod), p.cod;
```

Comment: The second one shows the result I was looking for. Thank you.